# How to consume .Net 4.0 REST WCF services?

Tags: .net-4.0, wcf-rest

I am having an ASP.NET 4 Web application. How can i consume a .Net 4.0 REST WCF service in this asp.net application.

Do i need to create proxyclass like for web services for REST too or is there some other way?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

this may help you : [Create REST service with WCF and Consume using jQuery](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/03/rest.html)

[Create, Host(Self Hosting, IIS hosting) and Consume WCF servcie](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/create-hostself-hosting-iis-hosting-and.html)